# Magento2 - Controller creates duplicate categories

Tags: magento2, category, category-listing, duplicate

I am creating a custom module to get `categories` and regarding products from `API` and uploading them to the site.

After creating a `controller` for `Categories`, in the backend, there are duplicate categories created for some categories.

I am not getting the issue as this is not happening for all other categories.

The issue is every time `Cron` runs it creates the same category again.

Below is the snapshot of my category page in the backend.

[image: duplicate categories]

[image: duplicate categories]

Comment: Have you check by disabling your customization?

Comment: Yes. I checked by doing that.

Comment: Then what is the result when you disable the customization?

Comment: There is no data upload when I disable the custom module. Because my module is uploading the categories. If I disable it, any kind of data is not going to upload.

Comment: If you are reading data from a 3rd party API and creating categories on basis of that in Magento, then you need to keep a track of already imported categories as the API will always return the same data. Is the API returning some unique ID for each of the categories which doesn't change?

Comment: Yes. I am reading data from 3rd party API. But getting an issue with these 3categories only.  And I checked API output it is not returning different ID for these 3 categories.